# Testing in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am following an introductory guide for OCaml and a program that I am working on is not working and I was wondering if I could get an explanation why.

```
let profit_500 : int = 
    let price = 500 in
    let attendees = 120 in
    let revenue = price * attendees in
    let cost = 18000 + 4 * attendees in
    revenue - cost;;

let test () : bool =
    (profitTest 500) = profit_500
;; run_test "profit at $5.00" test
```

At line (profitTest 500) = profit_500 I am getting Error: Unbounded value profit test.  Can someone explain why?  This is my first excursion into OCaml, but I know some java.  Can someone also explain why the last ;; goes before run_test instead of after profit_500 (or is that the same)?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't know OCAML, but what are you expecting `(profitTest 500) = profit_500` to do? It looks very off. Also, you probably don't need all those `let...in`s. I'd think you should be able to group all the bindings under a single `let`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate OCaml requires a `let` for every binding. That syntax is correct.

Comment: @ElanHamburger Really? That's unfortunate. My bad.

Comment: Is this OUnit or some other testing framework? `profitTest` is unbound because, well, you never bound it. Can you link to the guide?

Answer (score 2):

It might help to spell out what "unbound" means. An unbound symbol (a name) is one that hasn't been defined. So OCaml is telling you that you haven't given a definition for `profitTest`. As @ElanHamburger says, this is true. There's no definition for a function with that name in the code you've shown.

If you're following an example in a guide, the most likely thing is that you need to type in the definition of `profitTest` (from the guide) before the definition of `test` as you give it.

Comment: This is one page in the middle of a discussion. Almost certainly the definition of `profitTest` appears on an earlier page.